# jQuery - Hide specific div whose name matches a pattern (p followed by a character, like p0, p1, pa, py)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, hide

I want to hide all elements within a div which have **class name starting with 'p' and followed by any character.**

```
<div id="myDiv">

   <div id="p0"> .... </div>
   <div id="p1"> ..... </div>

   <div id="abc"> .... </div>

</div>
```

So I want to hide the 'p0' and 'p1' div and leave 'abc' div.

I am trying following code

```
$('#myDiv').find('#p*').hide();
```

But obviously this is wrong. Please suggest me how to use wild card with jQuery selector.

Let me know if more code is required.

Comment: the `p0` and `p1` divs already look pretty well hidden to me ;-)

Comment: sorry for the typo, i edited it

Comment: @Saumitra: ...and I've gone in and fixed the remaining q's.

Comment: @Curt: LOL! And now it looks like Saumitra meant q, not p, and has gone in and *mostly* changed it back. Yeesh. *Edit:* Ah, okay, we've settled on p.

Comment: :( now my joke doesn't make sense

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an [attribute-starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('div[id^="p"]').hide();
```

Example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s838K/1/)

Answer (score 3):

[@EmreErkan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10553395/370103) has posted a working solutions. However I would suggest the better method would be to add a common class or data-attribute to the DIVs so you can select them better.

For example...

```
<div id="p0" class="HideMe" data-noshow="true"> .... </div>
<div id="p1" class="HideMe" data-noshow="true"> ..... </div>
```

and you can hide them like so:

```
$(".HideMe").hide();
```

or

```
$("div[data-noshow='true']").hide();
```

Comment: I will use you solution because it is cleaner...But I will mark EmreErkan solution as answer because of my question. And sorry for making your joke obsolete ;-)